# How to autocrop video using FFMPEG and powershell

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

It should be possible to parse the output from ffmpeg's cropdetect command (to remove black borders) `ffmpeg -ss 90 -i out.mkv -vframes 10 -vf cropdetect -f null` and directly apply given output to the command `ffmpeg -i out.mkv -vf "crop=h:w:x:y" YourCroppedMovie.mp4`. Parameters are height, width, x start and y start.

How to apply the given result to the second command in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[string]$STDOUT_FILE = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath "stdout.txt"
$ArgumentList = "-ss 90 -i out.mkv -vframes 10 -vf cropdetect -f null -"
Start-Process -FilePath ffmpeg -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardError $STDOUT_FILE
$crop = (((Get-Content -LiteralPath $STDOUT_FILE | Where-Object { $_ -Like '*crop=*' }).Split(" "))[13]).Split("=")[1]


$ArgumentList = '-i out.mkv -vf "crop=' + $crop + '" YourCroppedMovie.mp4'
Start-Process -FilePath ffmpeg -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Each line

1st just sets variable name and the location for the file that ffmpeg's output is captured

2nd was the command line you used in your example

3rd starts ffmpeg with your commands, it waits until ffmpeg is done, it captures ffmpeg's standard error info in file set in line 1

4th Loads the captured file, searches for a line containing "crop=", it then splits that line at every space " ", the 14th segment contains the crop into, it splits that 14th segment at the "=" sign, it then sets the 2nd segment (data after = sign) as $crop

5th sets your command line but adds the crop info ($crop)

6th runs ffmpeg with new command line and waits for it to finish

Comment: Thank you! Could you, however, please explain your code a little?

Comment: Edited post for info